# Synchronize two displays of a view?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, panels, views, 7

I have a view with several tiers of arguments, navigated like so:

Camp > Date > Photo Gallery

I need a way to display a block of all the tags associated with the given content. So when Camp is selected, I need to display the tags associated with content for that camp. When Date is selected, I need to display the tags associated with content for that date AND that camp.

I've tinkered with [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels), I've installed [EVA](http://drupal.org/project/eva), I tried [Views Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_field), and I just can't figure out how to do this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working, and I didn't need Eva, Views Field, or Panels. I just needed good ol' fashioned Views.

I created a View with a Page and a Block.

Page displays images and takes contextual filters Term (of vocab Camp) and Date. 
When the value is not in the URL, a summary is displayed.

Block displays Terms (of vocab Tags) and takes the same two contextual filters. When the filter value is not available, I choose Provide default value > Raw value from URL > and select relevant path component.

I set the block to display on all pages, but on pages that don't pass it recognized arguments it just doesn't appear because it's empty.

Voilá. So much simpler than I thought.